# JS Flexigrid isn't showing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flexigrid

I'm trying to migrate a website from an IIS to an Apache server. (on Ubunutu) The site is fairly simple, it simply displays data that is being stored in an Oracle database. The data is displayed in a jQuery Flexigrid component.

My issue is that although the flexigrid is created, it never displays the data. The load images continues to spin at the bottom saying "Processing..." but it never stops.

I have verified that the json string returned from the ajax script is correctly formatted and contains data.

The site is using jQuery 1.2.6. I'm at a loss because in the same browser, going to the site on the IIS server works fine, but going to the site on the apache server fails to display the data. This doesn't make sense to me though because it seems to be a problem with JS, since both sites are giving the exact same JSON string to the client.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to this issue?  I have the exact same issue happening: JSON looks fine, but FlexiGrid just spins saying "Processing"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too, but I managed to solved it.

the JSON string must be in correct, valid format, or else the loading image will spin forever.
try to double qoute everything, not single quote.

**[Go here to read to see the same discussion and result](http://code.google.com/p/flexigrid/issues/detail?id=23)**

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your jquery script from google may solve your problem.

Also, if you get the latest flexigrid.js from github, you have to update your jquery. If the problem remains, check JSON format. You can check the new JSON code of flexigrid (for php file) from https://github.com/paulopmx/Flexigrid/tree/master/demo